# jQuery post/ajax post problem

Tags: php, jquery

HI im trying to send a jquery post/ajax to send some variables to a php file.

```
<script src="/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var music ='';
var genre ='';
var language ='';
var nasheedid = "<? echo $postid; ?>";
var session = "<? echo $_SESSION['SESS_TMP']; ?>";

$(function(){
$('.submit').click(function(){
var postdata = {pmusic: music, pgenre: genre, plang: language, psession: session};

$.ajax({
type: 'post',
cache: false,
url: 'addmusic.php',
data: postdata,
success: function (msg) {
alert(msg);
},
dataType: "text",
});

}); 
});
```

now regardless of where i post the stuff to, (even if i change the url to url: blahblah.php123 I still get the same results (which is):

The alert displays the entire source code of the file (that the above code is on)

Comment: Are you sure that PHP is working properly on your computer?  And are you accessing it through http://localhost ?  To make sure, right-click and View Source.  If you see PHP (like `<?php echo $postid; ?>`), then it's either not installed, not configured properly, or not going through the server.

Comment: You sure your server is running and PHP is enabled?

Comment: thanks guys i fixed the problem myself. My server was using rewrite so i had to use: url: "/addmusic.php", instead of url: "addmusic.php"

Comment: @abz121 In which case, please consider adding an answer to this question yourself and accept it, that way the question will be counted as closed, and future developers which have the same problem as you will benefit from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks guys i fixed the problem myself. My server was using rewrite so i had to use `url: "/addmusic.php"` instead of `url: "addmusic.php"`.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are having an exception on those pages and its redirecting to the same page so you are seeing the same page everytime. Try to debug your server side code and see.

Answer (score 0):

So you see the PHP code in the alert?  There are a few causes for this.

1. You don't have a WAMP stack installed.  If not, you need to install WampServer or XAMPP.
2. It's not configured properly.  It could be that PHP isn't setup correctly.
3. Your configuration doesn't support short tags (`<?`).  Try changing them to `<?php`.
4. You're not accessing the file through the server properly.  Look at the beginning of the URL, make sure it starts with http://localhost/ .

You might also try using [`jQuery.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) instead.

It's also best to use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json-encode) when outputting from PHP to Javascript.

```
var nasheedid = <?php echo json_encode($postid); ?>;
var session = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['SESS_TMP']); ?>;
```

It will take care of quoting, escaping, etc.